# Solving a system expressed under a matrix-vector form

Tags: linear-algebra

Just wondering how to evaluate this, is there a quicker way to evaluate this without multiplying each row entry of the first matrix by the entries of the second matrix and setting it to equal $0$, then doing the same for the second row of the first matrix?

$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-\sqrt{17}}{2} & -1 \\ -4 & \frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2} \end{bmatrix}  $$\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\ v_2\end{bmatrix} = 0$

Comment: The sign in your first entry is probably a '+' instead of '=' (based on the fact that they are on the same button on my keyboard)?

Comment: I changed the equal sign to a $+$. However, i wonder if there still isn't a typo... should the $1$ and the $-1$ in the numerators really have different signs?

Comment: no it was correct before

Comment: @user123: there was an equal sign before, so I am pretty sure that was not correct either ;)

Comment: oh sorry I had a typo

Comment: it is correct now

Comment: Note that the determinant in this case becomes zero, so you will have an infinite number of solutions, since it is a homogeneous system. (It is $\frac{1}{4}(17 -1) -4 = \frac{16}{4} - 4 = 0$)

Comment: Either there is no nontrivial solution, or else the nontrivial solution is what you get by ignoring one of the two equations and using only one of them (because you can use row reduction to eliminate one of the equations, since the two rows will be multiples of each other.) The latter situation is quite common when computing eigenvectors of small matrices by hand when the eigenvalues are "nasty" like this. In particular, in this situation it is not necessary to *check* that there is a nontrivial solution, provided you correctly obtained the eigenvalue whose eigenvector you are computing.

Comment: that latter situation is correct, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Simply pick either equation you like, arbitrarily decide a (nonzero) value for one of the variables, and then solve that one equation for the other variable.

Comment: so I can choose any non zero value? so if I let v2=1 then I get my proper v1

Comment: @Ian so then I must let v2=1 in my final answer? and because I am choosing a non zero value then there can be infinitely many answers? and my answer will be correct as long as my calculations are correct

Comment: Could easily have been solved by looking _**online**_ for a solution. Poor question, but not enough for a downvote...

Comment: There are infinitely many valid answers, yes; probably the most convenient thing I can think of would be to take $v_1=2$ (to cancel the denominator out).

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the first row by
$$
1+\sqrt{17}
$$
and the second row by $-2$, so the system becomes
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-8 & -1-\sqrt{17}\\
8 & 1+\sqrt{17}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}=0
$$

On the other hand, if this system comes from the calculation of an eigenvector, you *know* that one equation suffices.

Indeed, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}
$$
then, by definition, the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a-\lambda & b \\ c & d-\lambda\end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank less than $2$. Thus in the system
$$
\begin{cases}
(a-\lambda)v_1+bv_2 = 0 \\[4px]
cv_1+(d-\lambda)v_2 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
one equation is a multiple of the other, so it's redundant for finding the solutions.

Let's see your particular case. The first equation is
$$
\frac{1-\sqrt{17}}{2}v_1-v_2=0
$$
which becomes
$$
v_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{17}}{2}v_1
$$
The second equation is
$$
-4v_1+\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2}v_2=0
$$
so
$$
\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}v_2=-4v_1
$$
that becomes
$$
v_2=\frac{-8}{1+\sqrt{17}}v_1=\frac{-8(1-\sqrt{17})}{1-17}v_1=
\frac{1-\sqrt{17}}{2}v_1
$$

Comment: why are you aloud to multiply any row by any number you choose?

Comment: @user123: it makes an equivalent system.

Comment: @egreg it does come from a calculation of a Eigen vector, so how does 1 equation suffice?

Comment: @user123 if $Ax = 0$ has a non-zero solution, then the rows of $A$ are necessarily linearly dependent.

Comment: so then how do I calculate it?

Comment: @user123 You're are solving a linear system; so you can multiply rows/equations by a nonzero number and get an equivalent system.

Answer (score 0):

$A\mathbf v = \mathbf 0$

There are two possibilities.  Either $A$ is non-singular, and the only solution is the trivial solution.

Or, $A$ is singular.  And every vector in the kernel of $A$ is in your solution set.

How do you find out if $A$ is singular?

You could do row operations, or you could find the determinant of $A$ and if it is zero the matrix is singular.

As it turns out $A$ is singular how do you find the kernel?

What is the dimension of the kernel?  It is $1.$  $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, and the dimension of the kernel is always less than or equal to the number of rows in the matrix.  And it is not a $0$ matrix.

If you find one vector in the kernel, as scalar multiples of that vector make up the kernel.

What is one vector in the kernel?

We use that the first row is of the from $(b,-1)$  then $(1,b)$ will be a solution.  It is obvious that the first row times this vector equals 0.  And since the second row vector is a scalar multiple of the first row vector.  The second row vector times $(1,b)$ will be a scalar multiple of $(b,-1)\cdot(1,b)$ and also equal $0.$

Answer (score 0):

Why not the standard way? It's not so tedious!
Multiplying by $-2$ the matrix, the corresponding system becomes.
$$
\begin{cases}
(\sqrt{17}-1 )x+2y=0\\
8x+(\sqrt{17}+1 )y=0
\end{cases}
$$
so, from the second equation, we have:
$$
x=-\frac{(\sqrt{17}+1)y}{8}
$$
and, substituting in the first e quation we find 
$$
-2y+2y=0 \quad \iff \quad y=t\qquad  \forall t \in \mathbb{R} 
$$
so the solution is :
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\dfrac{(\sqrt{17}+1)t}{8}\\
t
\end{pmatrix}
$$